# XML Sparql results from rdflib

Tags: rdflib

I am using `Graph()` in RDFLib, i am correctly getting results of from the graph using sparql. Is it possible to get the results directly in HTML table format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rdflib` is a library to work with rdf in python, not an HTML rendering engine. Usually if you work on a `graph.sparql()` query, you want to access the result in python itself.

That said, there is a fork focusing on hosting RDF called `rdflib-web`. In it you can find a [`htmlresults.py`](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-web/blob/master/rdflib_web/htmlresults.py) which does pretty much what i think you want.